# C# CheckBox Question

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have HTML Generated Checkboxes on a page. How can I check to see if they are 'Checked' with c#? I am looking to use an if statement

```
if (checkbox.checked = true)
   {
        // EXECUTE CODE HERE
   }
```

I don't know how to call the element since it's HTML.

For my HTML I use another aspx to generate the HTML

```
FileListLabel.Text += ("<input type='checkbox' name='option" + counter +
                       "' value='" + SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["ID"].ToString()) +
                       "'>" + SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["LinkFilename"].ToString()) + "<BR>");
```

Is there a way to make that runat server? Or Should I use the Request.Form?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show some of your HTML? Are you using ASP.Net? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Can't provide solid answer here, but I guess you should be able to get the html using the WebBrowser object, followed by using something similar to getElementById(myCheckboxId).attribute("checked"); Note that I havn't tested this, but see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# you either need to have the checkboxes declared as `runat="server"` to access by name, or check the `Request.Form` for the value.

Answer (score 2):

An HTML checkbox will only be submitted if it is checked.

So, if it exists in the postback, it was checked.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should do this with javascript only in a way like 
`<input onclick="__doPostBack('__Page', 'yourCheckboxNumberNIsChecked');" />` // where yourCheckboxNumberNIsChecked is flag which you will set when you define that checkbox has  property checked set in "true". Then in code-behind you can define this event in a such way:

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
   Dim eventArg As String = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
   If eventArg = "yourCheckboxNumberNIsChecked" Then
       Response.Write("You check it !")
   End If
End If
```